# Stuck on an assignment. At least part of it. ATM Banking choices

Tags: python, python-3.x

below is my code that I have worked on to get this bank atm assignment going. I can't seem to add and subtract into the balance of the code. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong. Below is what the part of what the assignment entails. Everything else is in working order in regards to choosing option P, S, and E. Options D, and W are where I have run into a problem.  Any help would be great. Thanks!

*If the user types D then:
·       Ask the user for the account number.
·        Search the accountnumbers() array for that account number and find its position.
·        Ask the user for the amount to be deposited.
·        Add the deposit amount to the balance for that account.
·        If the user types W then:
·        Ask the user for the account number.
·        Search the accountnumbers() array for that account number and find its position.
·        Ask the user for the amount to be withdrawn.
·        Subtract withdrawal amount from  the  balance for that account.*

```
namelist=[]
accountnumberslist=[]
balancelist=[]

def populatelist():
    print ('Great! Please enter the information below')
    namecount=0
    #This loops collects the five names,accounts,balances, and appends them to the namelist
    while(namecount< 2):
        name= input('Enter a name: ')
        namelist.append(name)
        accountnumber = input('Please enter your Account Number: ')
        accountnumberslist.append(accountnumber)
        balances = input('Please enter your Balance: ')
        balancelist.append(balances)
        namecount = namecount + 1
    return

def displayall():
    print ('I am inside display function')
    position =0
    #This loop, prints one name at a time from the zero position to the end. 
    while ( position < 2):
        displayone(position)
        position = position + 1
    return

def displayone(position):
    print ('Account Holder:',namelist[position])
    print ('Balance:',balancelist[position])
    return

def calculatedeposit():
      position = 0
      while (position < 2):
        depamount = int(input('Please enter the amount to deposit'))
        balancelist[position] = balancelist[position] + depamount
        position = position + 1
      return      

def calculatewithdrawal()
       position = 0
       while (position < 2):
        withmount = int(input('Please enter the amount to deposit'))
        balancelist[position] = balancelist[position] + withamount
        position = position + 1

#What does it receive. Account Number to search.
#what does it do? Searches for the Account Holder.
#what does it send back. Position of the Account Holder, if not found, -1
def searchforacct(accounttosearch):
    foundposition=-1  # assume that it is not going to be found. 
    position=0
    while (position < 2):
        if (accounttosearch==accountnumberslist[position]):
            foundposition = position
            break
        position = position + 1
    return foundposition

#This function will display the menu, collect the users response and send back
def displaymenu():
    print ('Enter P to Populate Data')
    print ('Enter S to Search for Account ')
    print ('Enter D to Deposit Amount ')
    print ('Enter W to Withdraw Amount ')
    print ('Enter E to Exit')
    choice = input('How can we help you today?:')
    return choice

print("=====================================")
print(" Welcome to Liberty City Bank ATM    ")
print("=====================================")
#main
response=''
while response!= 'E' and response!='e':
    response = displaymenu()
    if response=='P' or response=='p':
        populatelist()
    elif response=='S' or response=='s':
        accounttosearch = input('Please enter the Account Number to search:')
        foundpos = searchforacct(accounttosearch)
        if ( foundpos == -1 ):
            print ('Account not found')
        else:
            displayone(foundpos)
    elif response=='D' or response=='d':
         accounttosearch = input('Please enter the Account Number for Deposit:')
         foundpos = searchforacct(accounttosearch)
         if ( foundpos == -1 ):
            print ('Account not found')
         else:
          calculatedeposit()

    elif response=='W' or response=='w':
          accounttosearch = input('Please enter the Account Number for Withdrawal:')
          foundpos = searchforacct(accounttosearch)
          if ( foundpos == -1 ):
            print ('Account not found')
          else:
            calculatewithdrawal()

    elif response=='E' or response=='e':
        print ('Thank you for choosing Liberty City Bank!')
        print ('Have a Nice Day!')
    else:
        print ('Invalid choice. Please try again')
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail in what way your code doesn't work as expected?

Comment: When calling `foundpos = searchforacct(accounttosearch)` (BTW, typing these in camelCase would make this a bit more readable) you set the position. But you reset the position when you call `calculatewithdrawal()` or `calculatedeposit()`. You need to pass that position as an *argument* to those two functions, and delete the `position = 0` line

Comment: You really shouldn't need a `while` loop within these at all... you're only updating one value at a time.

Comment: Last remark, `balancelist` is a list of *strings*... you never cast them to ints so you're adding/subtracting ints and strings. HTH

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. You Mangohero1, you were right regarding the "while's".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code wont compile, on line 45 add a : following your def. On line 45 change `withamount to withmount`. Then on Line 45 change

```
balancelist[position] = balancelist[position] + withamount
```

to this

```
 balancelist[position] = int(balancelist[position]) - withamount
```

You need to cast the string in your balance list to an int. You also need to subtract (-) not add (+) from the list as its a withdrawal.

There are a few other bugs in your code but thats enough to get you up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking at the 'account' you found from the users input, you loop through the first 2 balance lists and add a user given value.